# How to use gather() function for multiple value arguments in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

I am new in the **tidyverse** data manipulation and I am using `gather()` function from the `tidyr` package for changing from wide to long form on my data.
I have the following `data` dataframe:

```
id <- 1:10
stim_1_ACC <- 0.5:10
stim_2_ACC <- 10:19
stim_1_RT <- 0.4:10
stim_2_RT <- 15:24
data <- data.frame(id,stim_1_ACC,stim_2_ACC,stim_1_RT,stim_2_RT)
```

I would have one column for `stim` in which I have `stim1` and `stim2` as values, and two columns `ACC` and `RT` as numeric variables.
With `gather()` function I can select only one `value` argument and so having doing what I want only for one variable.

```
data %>%
  gather(key = "Stimuli", value = "ACC", 2:5)
```

I reach my goal with multiple steps, splitting and then binding dataframe columns, but I'm looking for a more tidy approach. Final results would be like this:

```
   id   stim  ACC  RT
1   1 stim_1  1.5 900
2   2 stim_1  2.5 901
3   3 stim_1  3.5 902
4   4 stim_1  4.5 903
5   5 stim_1  5.5 904
6   6 stim_2  6.5 905
7   7 stim_2  7.5 906
8   8 stim_2  8.5 907
9   9 stim_2  9.5 908
10 10 stim_2 10.5 909
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably , after gathering you'll need to use `extract`/`separate` to separate `"stim.."` and `"RT"/"ACC"` component and then use `spread`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  gather(key, value, -id) %>%
  extract(key, into = c("stim", "temp"), regex = "(stim_\\d+)_(.*)") %>%
  spread(temp, value)
```

Comment: Works perfectly... can you explain a little bit the `regex=` argument? or can you suggest some documentation?

Comment: @FilippoGambarota `regex` is used to tell how we want to separate the columns based on the capture groups. In this case as we want to separate into two column so we have two capture groups one with `stim_\\d+` part and remaining part of the string as second column. You can read more about it in `?extract`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `separate` to split the 'key' column into 'stim' and 'temp' by splitting at the '_' before the character element

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
   gather(key, value, -id) %>% 
   separate(key, into = c("stim", "temp"), sep="(_)(?=[A-Z])") %>%
   spread(temp, value)
```